# Как выровнять диалоговое окно под кнопкой JQuery

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно

Есть код JQuery, который подставляет окно точно под кнопку "Корзина". Но если кнопка располагается в правом углу экрана, всплывающее под ней окно выходит за размер экрана. Как можно сделать, что бы это окно подстраивалось под положение экрана и не уезжало?
[image: иллюстрация проблемы]

```
let position = this.offset(); 
  if (pos.top >= $(document).height() / 2 && pos.left >= $(document).width() / 2 ){
$("#okno")
     .css({
       top:'${position.top + 20}px',
       left: '${position.left}px'
    })
    .show();
```

Неправильное условие вычисления, но не пойму, что не так

Comment: Использовать right вместо left?

Comment: Есть меню где эти кнопки от левого края до правого края экрана. Условия или left или right могут уже не сработать...

Comment: Кто мешает использовать оба сразу? Кто мешает ограничивать размерами экрана?

Comment: Мешает практически нулевое знание языка))

Comment: Ну если только это - опишите алгоритм псевдокодом, - попробую помочь с его переводом на JS.

Comment: Переписал код в вопросе

 (и так четыре условия с разными операторами сравнения, для определения части экрана) Окно в итоге отображается, но позиция не считается, не правильно написана, но я не понимаю что тут не так, к сожалению. " if (pos.top>= $(document).height() / 2 && pos.left >= $(document).width() / 2 ) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let position = this.offset(); 
  if (pos.top >= $(document).height() / 2 && pos.left >= $(document).width() / 2 ){
$("#okno")
     .css({
       top:'${position.top + 20}px',
       left: '${position.left - 20}px'
    })
    .show()
```

работает.